# JQuery DatePicker ignores DateFormat

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a datepicker component in my C# app, which takes its default value from the server through AJAX call. The problem is, it ignores the date format I've defined as a parameter. I looked into the code and it seems that the date format is not set on the `settings` variable, so JQuery uses the default value (mm/dd/yy).

Here is my code:

```
$.when(_getUserProfileValue(defValue))
    .done(function (result) {
        // result is 23.07.2015
        // this line shows the correct date and format
        $("#divTest").text(result.d);
       // new Date(res) gives back invalid date, but datepicker shows the result from server
       // without this line, datepicker shows a completely wrong date
       // TODO: format is still ignored
       var aDate = new Date(result.d);
       $calendar.datepicker({
           dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy"
       });
       $calendar.datepicker("setDate", aDate);
   })
```

Any ideas?

Comment: $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat","Your date format");
for detail you can also check the following url
https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats

Comment: @luckwithu, thanks! But the other answer is faster ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be because you have already initialized the datepicker on that element, in that case to update the date format of an existing datepicker use the [option method](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-option) like

```
$calendar.datepicker('option', 'dateFormat', "dd.mm.yy");
```

Comment: Wow, you're right. Thank you! Actually I've read this line yesterday in JQuery Docs, but didn't think that might be the answer, d'oh!

Comment: You might want to just set the dateFormat correctly in the other place the datepicker is being initialized and remove `$calendar.datepicker()` from here. Just do setDate once you get the `new Date()` working correctly.

Comment: @AndrewR, yes, that would be the correct way. Only I need to set the dateFormat dynamically later. Sorry, was not so clear in my post :)